# Find: combine -depth with -prune to feed cpio

Tags: find

I'm building a backup script where some directories should not be included in the backup archive.

```
cd /;
find . -maxdepth 2 \ 
    \( -path './sys' -o -path './dev' -o -path './proc' -o -path './media' -o -path './mnt' \) -prune \
-o -print
```

This finds only the files and directories I want.

Problem is that `cpio` should be fed with the following option in order to avoid problems with permissions when restoring files.

```
find ... -depth ....
```

And if I add the `-depth` option, returned files and directories include those I want to avoid.

I really don't understand these sentences from the find manual:

```
-prune True;  if  the  file is a directory, do not descend into it. If
              -depth is given, false; no  effect.   Because  -delete  implies
              -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation of what the manual says is this:

When `find` gets to a directory that matches your `-path` expression, `-prune` will avoid going inside it. So `find` will go

```
/             ok, go inside
/home         ok, go inside
/home/xxxx    ok, go inside
/tmp          don't go inside
/var          ..etc...
```

But when you use `-depth`, it processes the inside of directories before the directories themselves. So it will match the path when it's too late:

```
/home/xxxx
/home         ok, go inside (it already went)
/tmp/zzzz     didn't match "-path /tmp", so it's ok
/tmp          don't go inside (too late!)
/var          ..etc...
/
```

To solve this problem you can try:

1. Just add new `-path` expressions with wildcards. This has the disadvantage that those subdirectories will be traversed anyway, just not printed (and their traversal will maybe trigger warnings)

   `find ... \( -path './sys' -o -path './sys/*' -o -path './dev' -o -path './dev/*' ... \) -prune ...`
2. Don't enumerate the directories to avoid, enumerate the ones to print!

   `find /bin /boot /etc /home /lib ...`

Comment: 1. If `...` is `-or ... -print`, one can drop the `-prune` before `-or`: they won't be printed anyway.

Answer (score 4):

[angus's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29979/find-combine-depth-with-prune-to-feed-cpio/29997#29997) explains why `-depth` doesn't work for you and proposes solutions.

It looks like you want to traverse a whole installation, but omit special filesystems like `/proc` and `/sys` and external devices. There's a better way to do this: use the `-xdev` primary on `find` to tell it not to descend into mount points. If you want to include some mounted filesystems in your backup, list them explicitly.

```
find / /home -xdev -depth -print
```

Comment: I've seen the -xdev option before but it doesn't fully suits my needs. Thank you for this idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using `-regex` if it's supported by your `find`:

```
find . -depth [...] -regex '\./\(sys\|dev\|proc\|media\|mnt\)\(/.*\)?' -prune -o -print
```

Note that `-regex` is not POSIX and might not be necessarily supported everywhere. Also the content of the directories will still be traversed.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step we reject the specific directories and then call in find with the -depth on the remaining to get the required format:

```
cd / && \
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \
   \( -name sys -o -name dev -o -name proc -o -name media -o -name mnt \) -prune -o \
   ! -name . -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -depth' {} {} \;
```